# Display player name based on score?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a score sheet program for the card game rummy. I'm having a problem displaying the name of the winner in a message box. The winner is the player with the fewest points. I put the final scores in an array and I am able to get the smallest score, but can't figure out how to display the wining player's name in a message box based on the score. Right now the message box just displays the first players name. The players names are displayed in labels in a different button. Thanks guys.

**Here's the code:**

```
Private Sub btnAddScores_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddScores.Click
    'player 1 scores:
    Dim Player1Game1 As Integer
    Dim Player1Game2 As Integer
    Dim Player1Game3 As Integer
    Dim Player1Game4 As Integer
    Dim Player1Game5 As Integer
    Dim Player1Game6 As Integer
    Dim Player1Game7 As Integer
    Dim Player1Game8 As Integer
    Dim Player1Game9 As Integer
    Dim Player1Game10 As Integer
    Dim Player1FinalScore As Integer

    'player 2 scores:
    Dim Player2Game1 As Integer
    Dim Player2Game2 As Integer
    Dim Player2Game3 As Integer
    Dim Player2Game4 As Integer
    Dim Player2Game5 As Integer
    Dim Player2Game6 As Integer
    Dim Player2Game7 As Integer
    Dim Player2Game8 As Integer
    Dim Player2Game9 As Integer
    Dim Player2Game10 As Integer
    Dim Player2FinalScore As Integer

    'player 3 scores:
    Dim Player3Game1 As Integer
    Dim Player3Game2 As Integer
    Dim Player3Game3 As Integer
    Dim Player3Game4 As Integer
    Dim Player3Game5 As Integer
    Dim Player3Game6 As Integer
    Dim Player3Game7 As Integer
    Dim Player3Game8 As Integer
    Dim Player3Game9 As Integer
    Dim Player3Game10 As Integer
    Dim Player3FinalScore As Integer

    'player 4 scores:
    Dim Player4Game1 As Integer
    Dim Player4Game2 As Integer
    Dim Player4Game3 As Integer
    Dim Player4Game4 As Integer
    Dim Player4Game5 As Integer
    Dim Player4Game6 As Integer
    Dim Player4Game7 As Integer
    Dim Player4Game8 As Integer
    Dim Player4Game9 As Integer
    Dim Player4Game10 As Integer
    Dim Player4FinalScore As Integer

    'player 5 scores:
    Dim Player5Game1 As Integer
    Dim Player5Game2 As Integer
    Dim Player5Game3 As Integer
    Dim Player5Game4 As Integer
    Dim Player5Game5 As Integer
    Dim Player5Game6 As Integer
    Dim Player5Game7 As Integer
    Dim Player5Game8 As Integer
    Dim Player5Game9 As Integer
    Dim Player5Game10 As Integer
    Dim Player5FinalScore As Integer

    'storing player 1 scores in varables 
    Player1Game1 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame1.Text
    Player1Game2 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame2.Text
    Player1Game3 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame3.Text
    Player1Game4 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame4.Text
    Player1Game5 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame5.Text
    Player1Game6 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame6.Text
    Player1Game7 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame7.Text
    Player1Game8 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame8.Text
    Player1Game9 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame9.Text
    Player1Game10 = tbPlayer1ScoreGame10.Text
    Player1FinalScore = (Player1Game1 + Player1Game2 + Player1Game3 + Player1Game4 + Player1Game5 + Player1Game6 + Player1Game7 + Player1Game8 + Player1Game9 + Player1Game10)

    'storing player 2 scores in varables 
    Player2Game1 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame1.Text
    Player2Game2 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame2.Text
    Player2Game3 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame3.Text
    Player2Game4 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame4.Text
    Player2Game5 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame5.Text
    Player2Game6 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame6.Text
    Player2Game7 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame7.Text
    Player2Game8 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame8.Text
    Player2Game9 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame9.Text
    Player2Game10 = tbPlayer2ScoreGame10.Text
    Player2FinalScore = (Player2Game1 + Player2Game2 + Player2Game3 + Player2Game4 + Player2Game5 + Player2Game6 + Player2Game7 + Player2Game8 + Player2Game9 + Player2Game10)

    'storing player 3 scores in varables 
    Player3Game1 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame1.Text
    Player3Game2 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame2.Text
    Player3Game3 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame3.Text
    Player3Game4 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame4.Text
    Player3Game5 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame5.Text
    Player3Game6 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame6.Text
    Player3Game7 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame7.Text
    Player3Game8 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame8.Text
    Player3Game9 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame9.Text
    Player3Game10 = tbPlayer3ScoreGame10.Text
    Player3FinalScore = (Player3Game1 + Player3Game2 + Player3Game3 + Player3Game4 + Player3Game5 + Player3Game6 + Player3Game7 + Player3Game8 + Player3Game9 + Player3Game10)

    'storing player 4 scores in varables 
    Player4Game1 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame1.Text
    Player4Game2 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame2.Text
    Player4Game3 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame3.Text
    Player4Game4 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame4.Text
    Player4Game5 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame5.Text
    Player4Game6 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame6.Text
    Player4Game7 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame7.Text
    Player4Game8 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame8.Text
    Player4Game9 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame9.Text
    Player4Game10 = tbPlayer4ScoreGame10.Text
    Player4FinalScore = (Player4Game1 + Player4Game2 + Player4Game3 + Player4Game4 + Player4Game5 + Player4Game6 + Player4Game7 + Player4Game8 + Player4Game9 + Player4Game10)

    'storing player 5 scores in varables 
    Player5Game1 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame1.Text
    Player5Game2 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame2.Text
    Player5Game3 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame3.Text
    Player5Game4 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame4.Text
    Player5Game5 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame5.Text
    Player5Game6 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame6.Text
    Player5Game7 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame7.Text
    Player5Game8 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame8.Text
    Player5Game9 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame9.Text
    Player5Game10 = tbPlayer5ScoreGame10.Text
    Player5FinalScore = (Player5Game1 + Player5Game2 + Player5Game3 + Player5Game4 + Player5Game5 + Player5Game6 + Player5Game7 + Player5Game8 + Player5Game9 + Player5Game10)

    'displays finals in labels 
    lblPlayer1FinalScore.Text = Player1FinalScore
    lblPlayer2FinalScore.Text = Player2FinalScore
    lblPlayer3FinalScore.Text = Player3FinalScore
    lblPlayer4FinalScore.Text = Player4FinalScore
    lblPlayer5FinalScore.Text = Player5FinalScore

    Dim WonArray(4) As Integer
    WonArray(0) = Player1FinalScore
    WonArray(1) = Player2FinalScore
    WonArray(2) = Player3FinalScore
    WonArray(3) = Player4FinalScore
    WonArray(4) = Player5FinalScore

   Dim WiningValue As Integer = (WonArray.Min)
    MsgBox(lblPlayerName1.Text)

   End sub
```

Comment: You can try using a `Dictionary` or a `DataTable` (instead of an array) to store points of the players. This way you'll be able to easily do any operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class which represent player's data

```
Public Class Player
    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Score As Integer

    Public Sub New(name As String)
        Name = name
    End Sub

    'Function For adding scores
    Public Sub AddPoints(points As Integer)
        _Score += points
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you can create list of players add players and points there and calculate min result with name

```
Private Sub btnAddScores_Click(ByVal sender As Object, 
                               ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddScores.Click
    Dim players = New List(Of Player)()

    'player 1 scores:
    Dim player1 As New Player("Player 1")

    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame1.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame2.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame3.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame4.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame5.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame6.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame7.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame8.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame9.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame10.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame1.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer1ScoreGame1.Text))

    players.Add(player1)

    'player 2 scores:
    Dim player2 As New Player("Player 1")
    player2.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame1.Text))
    player2.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame2.Text))
    player2.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame3.Text))
    player2.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame4.Text))
    player2.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame5.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame6.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame7.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame8.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame9.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame10.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame1.Text))
    player1.AddPoints(Integer.Parse(tbPlayer2ScoreGame1.Text))

    players.Add(player2)

    'and so on for other players

    'displays finals in labels 
    lblPlayer1FinalScore.Text = player1.Score.ToString()
    lblPlayer2FinalScore.Text = player2.Score.ToString()
    lblPlayer3FinalScore.Text = player3.Score.ToString()
    lblPlayer4FinalScore.Text = player4.Score.ToString()
    lblPlayer5FinalScore.Text = player5.Score.ToString()

    Dim minScores As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
    Dim winner As Person
    For Each tempPlayer As Player In players
        If (tempPlayer.Scores < minScores)
            winner = tempPlayer
        End If
    Next

    Dim message As String = $"Winner is {winner.Name} with {winner.Score} points."

    MessageBox.Show(message)
End sub
```

Set `Option Strict On` in your project or at least in the first line of your code file. This will give you fast feedback about possible type converting error during compile time.

Also consider using `DataGridView` instead of multiply textboxes. if number of games (10) is constant, then you can use `DataGridView` with 10 columns and 5 rows for players.